# jQuery - $.ajax(); goes to the next page on submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a button that is red if the user didn't read the term and conditions. If the user click on the Acknowledge button, it'll post the date and time into the database and then return a disabled button in green. However, when I submit, it goes directly to the next page. Can anyone please tell me what's wrong with my code?

Mark up:

```
<div class="acknowledge">
    <form method="post" name="blitzread" action="blitzread.php" id="submit">
        <input type="hidden" name="emp_id" value="<?php echo $emp_id; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="current_time" value="<?php echo $current_time; ?>">
        <button type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-large btn-danger">Acknowledge</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#submit').submit(function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        success: function(response) {
            $('.acknowledge').html("<button class="btn btn-large btn-success disabled">Acknowledge</button>");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: After adding e to function(e) you might also want to add e.stopPropagation() after e.preventDefault().

Comment: You need to pass the event obect to you function: `$('#submit').submit(function(e) {` -- note the `e` passed as a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put `e` argument in your `function()`:

Your code should be like this:

```
$('#submit').submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    $.ajax({
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        success: function(response) {
            $('.acknowledge').html('<button class="btn btn-large btn-success disabled">Acknowledge</button>');
        }
    });
    return false;

});
```

Here is fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/zur4ik/WVssV/

Comment: Because there was error with quotes on `$('.acknowledge').html("");`
Look on my code upper, there is with single quotes: `$('.acknowledge').html('');`

Comment: One double-quote was opening on `.html("` and then another was closing on `class="`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `e` is undefined.

The first argument of the function is the jQuery event object, on which you can call [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/). So your code should look like this:

```
$('#submit').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to get the `e` argument

```
$('#submit').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        success: function(response) {
            $('.acknowledge').html("<button class="btn btn-large btn-success disabled">Acknowledge</button>");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```